# ASPI.net core Fields can not deseialize a json but properties can

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-5

I am using dotnet 5 and I have a HTTP controller as follows

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

namespace Service.Controllers
{
    [ApiController]
    [Route("[controller]")]
    public class ProfanityCheckerController : ControllerBase
    {
        [HttpGet]
        public int Get()
        {
            return 1;
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult Post(ServiceInput Input)
        {
            ProfanityChecker.Check(Input.Sentence);
            return Ok();
        }
    }
}
```

and ServiceInput class as defined as

```
namespace Service
{
    public class ServiceInput
    {
        public string Sentence;
        public int Foo;
    }
}
```

I am using Rested on firefox to send data to contoller. If I send data like

```
{
"Sentence" : "qweqweqwe",
"Foo" : 123
}
```

I can get a breakpoint in the controller, but I get default values of `Sentence` (null) and `Foo` (0). However, if I change the class definition such that they are properties and not fields, everything works just fine. I have never faced such scenario in .net core 3.1. Is this something new? Am I missing something?

Comment: rough guess try sending with small case json data .ie {"sentence":"jhjhk", "foo":123}

Comment: @Satindersingh doesn't work either

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, fields are ignored.
Try adding [JsonInclude] to your fields.

```html
namespace Service
{
    public class ServiceInput
    {
        [JsonInclude]
        public string Sentence;
        
        [JsonInclude]
        public int Foo;
    }
}
```

```html
var options = new JsonSerializerOptions
{
    IncludeFields = true,
};
var forecast = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Forecast>(json, options);
```

Comment: JsonInclude works. But can you tell me why I need it for fields but not for properties? I believe I never had this issue in .net 3.1 or earlier

Comment: I don't know. The documentation for 3.1 say that they are ignored. For 5 there is the addition to include them. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-how-to?pivots=dotnet-core-3-1

Comment: Can you also point me to the documentation? I'll close the question and mark your post as the answer

Comment: .net 3.1: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-how-to?pivots=dotnet-core-3-1#serialization-behavior and .net 5: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-how-to?pivots=dotnet-core-3-1#serialization-behavior